# RaspberryPi is not booting

Tags: raspberry-pi

i am working with a RaspberryPI 3 B. I started to boot the Rasp yesterday and this happend:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have no idea what happend. How can I solve or enter the black screen?

How can I check what the problem is ?

Comment: This is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. It can instead be posted to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/, but make sure to comply with their [on-topic](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rules.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can have many reasons.

Try to boot new fresh raspbian for control.

First check your SD Card and empty space on it.

Also try press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to reach text console.

I wish you luck!